# javascript not executing instead it shows the function name in the address bar

Tags: javascript, html

I made a lot of "js-classes" in various files with numerous functions - the project is just too huge to post the code.

Somehow I managed directly at the finish line to create a bug. Meaning in some browser (ff for example) it doesn't execute the desired function (which it does properly in an earlier stage without changing the code behind executing that function and without changing the code of the function in the meantime).

I created js-classes and the underlaying functions with this scheme:

```
function ClassName(){
   this.FunctionName = function(){
   //something
   }
}
```

what I get in the Address bar is: javascript:ClassName.FunctionName()
what should happen is that it the browser just executes the function as chrome does for example, without anything going wrong.

So I am guessing that there is just a  bad character somewhere in the code that I can't find (which doesn't belong there) or a missing " somewhere else (maybe also in another class) - or anything like that - which lets some browser interpret it right (chrome under windows and safari under mac but not under windows for example) and others don't.

But what I am hoping is some clue from one of the professionals at Stack Overflow to tell me either what it could be because of that behavior with the address bar or how to find those missing characters or those which simply doesn't belong to the code. Whats the best practice, any tools maybe?

chrome and ie developer tools (f12) and firefox firebug didn't gave me any console errors so I am really clueless right now, maybe its in the html? I could post the html, cause its not to big because most of the contents gets created by the js.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <title>
        engine demo build
    </title>

    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle" media="screen">
        @import "style_l.css";
    </style>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <meta name="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta name="Language" content="english, en-us">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.KeyboardDefines.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.HelpFunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.BagaObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.CollisionRect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.ImageObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.ParallaxLayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.LevelObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.SpriteImageObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.Player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Adventure.Player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Gate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Switch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Box.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Dragon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Crane.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Golem.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.Obstacles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.ObstaclesGround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Adventure.ObstaclesGround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Adventure.ObstaclesGroundCastle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Adventure.ConversationIndicator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.ObstaclesCeiling.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.Obstacles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.ObstaclesGround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.ObstaclesGolemGround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.ObstaclesSpikes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.ObstaclesGroundLow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JumpAndRun.ObstaclesGoals.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Autoscroller.GoalObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GameEngine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.EngineCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Engine.FPSObject.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class='GAMEmt-std'></div>

    <div id='debug'></div>

    <div id='GAMEglobalwrapper'>
        <div id='sounds'>
            <div id='bgmusic'>
                <audio id='l1bg' loop>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Longing_for_Tumbleweeds_by_Admiral_Bob_feat_Snowflake.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Longing_for_Tumbleweeds_by_Admiral_Bob_feat_Snowflake.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>

                    <p>seeing this message can have 2 possible causes:
                    <br>
                    1. You are using a browser which is not supported or
                    <br>
                    2. You are using Safari on windows (or linux? - not tested till now)
                    <br><br>
                    Solution:
                    <br>
                    In the first case get a supported browser
                    <br>
                    In the second case download Apple Quicktime, close Safari, install Quicktime, run Quicktime till advertisement appears, close Quicktime, run Safari again, browse to this site.
                </audio><!--l1bg-->

                <audio id='l2bg' loop>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Two_Swords_by__ghost.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Two_Swords_by__ghost.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--l2bg-->

                <audio id='l3bg' loop>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Real_good_day_by_calling_sister_midnight.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Real_good_day_by_calling_sister_midnight.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--l2bg-->

                <audio id='l4bg' loop>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Dance_of_Light_Pixies_by_onlymeith.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Dance_of_Light_Pixies_by_onlymeith.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--l4bg-->

                <audio id='scenebg' loop>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Longing_spacious_choir_remix_by_zep_hurme.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/musicTracks/Longing_spacious_choir_remix_by_zep_hurme.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--l2bg-->
            </div><!--bgmusic-->

            <div id='soundfx'>
                <audio id='hitsound'>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/standardHit.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/standardHit.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--hitsound-->

                <audio id='switchsound'>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/switch.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/switch.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--switchsound-->

                <audio id='gatesound'>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/gate.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/gate.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--gatesound-->

                <audio id='boxsound'>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/box.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
                    <source src='assets/audio/soundFX/box.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
                </audio><!--boxsound-->
            </div><!--soundfx-->
        </div><!--sounds-->

        <canvas id="canvas" ondrop="GLOBAL_gameEngine.drop(event)" ondragover="GLOBAL_gameEngine.allowDrop(event)" width="800" height="450"> 
            <p>You will need a current version of a major browser to play this game</p>
        </canvas>

        <div id='gameoverscreen'>
            <div id='gameover'></div>

            <div id='lvl1gameover'>
                <a href=javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.restartLevel1()>Try Again</a>
            </div><!--lvl1gameover-->

            <div id='lvl2gameover'>
                <a href=javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.resetAtCheckpoint()>Reset At Last Checkpoint</a>
            </div><!--lvl2gameover-->

            <div id='lvl4gameover'>
                <a href=javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.restartLevel4()>Somenone saw you. Try again. -></a>
            </div><!--lvl4gameover-->
        </div><!--gameover-->

        <div id='storyscreen'>
            <div id='languagepicker'>
                <!--a href=javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.setLanguage('en')-->English (soon)<!--/a-->
                <br><br>
                <a href=javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.setLanguage('de')>Deutsch</a>
            </div><!--languagepicker-->

            <div id='sequenz1'>
                <div id='sequenz1question'>
                </div><!--sequenz1question-->

                <div id='sequenz1img'>
                </div><!--sequenz1img-->

                <div id='sequenz1txt'>
                </div><!--sequenz1txt-->
            </div><!--sequenz1-->

            <div id='sequenz2'>
                <div id='sequenz2question'>
                </div><!--sequenz2question-->

                <div id='sequenz2img'>
                </div><!--sequenz2img-->

                <div id='sequenz2txt'>
                </div><!--sequenz2txt-->
            </div><!--sequenz2-->

            <div id='sequenz3'>
                <div id='sequenz3question'>
                </div><!--sequenz3question-->

                <div id='sequenz3img'>
                </div><!--sequenz3img-->

                <div id='sequenz3txt'>
                </div><!--sequenz3txt-->
            </div><!--sequenz3-->

            <div id='sequenz4'>
                <div id='sequenz4question'>
                </div><!--sequenz4question-->

                <div id='sequenz4img'>
                </div><!--sequenz4img-->

                <div id='sequenz4txt'>
                </div><!--sequenz4txt-->
            </div><!--sequenz4-->

            <div id='sequenz5'>
                <div id='sequenz5question'>
                </div><!--sequenz5question-->

                <div id='sequenz5img'>
                </div><!--sequenz5img-->

                <div id='sequenz5txt'>
                </div><!--sequenz5txt-->
            </div><!--sequenz5-->

            <div id='conversation' ondrop="GLOBAL_gameEngine.drop(event)" ondragover="GLOBAL_gameEngine.allowDrop(event)">
                <div id='conversationplayertxt'>
                </div><!--conversationplayertxt-->

                <div id='conversationvillagertxt'>
                </div><!--conversationvilagertxt-->

                <div id='conversationdirection'>
                </div><!--conversationdirection-->

                <div id='conversationimg'>
                </div><!--conversationImage-->
            </div><!--conversation-->
        </div><!--storyscreen-->

        <div id='hint' draggable='false'>
        </div><!--hint-->

        <div id='gui'>
            <div id='healthmeter'>
                <div id='hp1'><img src='assets/visuals/images/heart.png'></div>
                <div id='hp2'><img src='assets/visuals/images/heart.png'></div>
                <div id='hp3'><img src='assets/visuals/images/heart.png'></div>
                <div class='clearleft'></div>
            </div>

            <div id='itembackpack'>
                <div id='pickaxe' alt='pickaxe' title='pickaxe' class='firstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/pickaxe.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "pickaxe")'></div>
                <div id='letter' alt='letter' title='letter' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/letter.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "letter")'></div>
                <div id='iron' alt='iron' title='iron' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/iron.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "iron")'></div>
                <div id='nails' alt='nails' title='nails' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/nails.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "nails")'></div>
                <div id='dagger' alt='dagger' title='dagger' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/dagger.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "dagger")'></div>
                <div id='book' alt='book' title='book' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/book.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "book")'></div>
                <div id='amulet' alt='amulet' title='amulet' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/amulet.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "amulet")'></div>
                <div id='ring' alt='ring' title='ring' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/ring.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "ring")'></div>
                <div id='mouse' alt='mouse' title='mouse' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/mouse.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "mouse")'></div>
                <div id='wasps' alt='wasps' title='wasps' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/wasps.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "wasps")'></div>
                <div id='dog' alt='dog' title='dog' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/dog.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "dog")'></div>
                <div id='sleepingpowder' alt='sleepingpowder' title='sleepingpowder' class='notfirstitem'><img src='assets/visuals/images/sleepingpowder.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.drag(event, "sleepingpowder")'></div>
            </div>
        </div><!--gui-->
    </div>

    <script>
        var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

        debug.log = function(){
            this.innerHTML = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            {
                this.innerHTML += arguments[i] + " ";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

forgot to mention: the page displays [object Object]

changed it to onclick and now i get: ReferenceError: GameEngine is not defined -seems like there is an closing bracket missing - i am searching right now, its not in the gameEngine which means its one of the classes above

the last error was a comment i accidentally did not commented out via "//" - onclick solved the problem

Many Thanks for the GREAT and FAST SUPERIOR support!!!
Now I can preparw everything to upload after getting rid of that performance issue i just found out.
Again a lot of thanks you really helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

instead of using the hrefs, you should make your links onclicks:

```
<a onclick="GLOBAL_gameEngine.restartLevel1()">Try Again</a>
```

Also, if you wanted to use the href, you still need to enclose your href in quotes

```
<a href="javascript:GLOBAL_gameEngine.restartLevel1()">Try Again</a>
```

Comment: Yeah that was an issue too, changed that but that did not changed the problem (clean cache etc. checked) - thanks for the quick helpfull reply

Comment: you're still getting the same problem when you use onclick instead of href?

Comment: no i changed it and now i get: ReferenceError: GameEngine is not defined -seems like there is an closing bracket missing - i am searching right now, its not in the gameEngine which means its one of the classes above

Comment: Doesn't seem like a missing bracket, you'd get many errors before that point. More likely, you're referencing an object that hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: It was a comment i accidentally did not commented out via "//" - seems like onclick solved the problem

Comment: good to hear. Please accept this answer so people who google know what's up.